# Python - Calculating ranks related to a dataframe column that includes blank cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

I have a Panda dataframe and want to produce an extra column that holds the ranks of an original column in the pd. However, the column has empty cells.  The ranks for those empty cells should be empty as well.

When I use

```
df['RRanked'] = df['R'].rank(ascending=1,na_option='keep')
```

it still produces a rank for the empty cells. In this case, the empty cell will get the highest rank.

How to produce empty ranks for those empty cells?

Thx!

Comment: What data type is column `R`? Are the undesired cells empty or are they None?

Comment: what you mean empty ranks? more like 0? cuz rank return None to missing value

Comment: type(df['R']) gives pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: well, when I use the command:  df['RRanked'] = df['R'].rank(ascending=1,na_option='keep') I do get a rank for a cell that is empty in R.  With empty I really mean empty here.  Just blank.

Comment: can you post example of your dataframe?

Comment: It comes from a webscraping operation using BS.  I might see a problem.  If I extract it as df['R] I get:
Name: R, dtype: object. Can that be the cause?

Comment: Not sure how I post the dataset here.

Comment: so empty cells are just empty string "" ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would coerce the column to a numeric value, then you can use rank with na_option='keep' which will not rank NaNs.

```
r = pd.to_numeric(df.R, errors='coerce')
rnk = r.rank(na_option='keep')
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that one as well. Without succes. Very peculiar thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it in a not so "clean" way.  I managed to replace all those cells by NaN. Then I used the kind answer by Yefet:  df['R'].apply(lambda x: pd.NA if x in ["NaN"] else x).rank(ascending=1). Later, I just replace the NaNs in the Ranks by "".  That works.